# Stripe - Webhook payload must be provided as a string or a Buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I am trying to code a subscription system with stripe. My following code is mostly copied from the stripe docs, but it always shows me this error:

```
Webhook signature verification failed. Webhook payload must b
e provided as a string or a Buffer (https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) instance representing the _raw_ request body.Payload was provided as a parsed JavaScript object instead.
Signature verification is impossible without access to the original signed material.
Learn more about webhook signing and explore webhook integration 
examples for various frameworks at https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing
```

This is my code written in javascript:

```
app.post(
  '/webhook',
  express.raw({ type: 'application/json' }),
  (request, response) => {
    let event = request.body;

    const endpointSecret = 'whsec_.....';

    if (endpointSecret) {

      const signature = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
      try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
          request.body,
          signature,
          endpointSecret
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`, err.message);
        return response.sendStatus(400);
      }
    }
    let subscription;
    let status;

    switch (event.type) {
      case 'customer.subscription.created':
        subscription = event.data.object;
        status = subscription.status;
        console.log(`Subscription status is ${status}.`);

        break;
      default:
        console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}.`);
    }
    response.send();
  }
);
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I have literally been searching the internet for an hour now and cant find anything. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's because `app.use(express.json());` code. Try to move webhook route before `app.use(express.json());`.

```js
// webhook route
app.post(
  '/webhook',
  express.raw({ type: 'application/json' }),
  (request, response) => {
    let event = request.body;

    const endpointSecret = 'whsec_.....';

    if (endpointSecret) {

      const signature = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
      try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
          request.body,
          signature,
          endpointSecret
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`, err.message);
        return response.sendStatus(400);
      }
    }
    let subscription;
    let status;

    switch (event.type) {
      case 'customer.subscription.created':
        subscription = event.data.object;
        status = subscription.status;
        console.log(`Subscription status is ${status}.`);

        break;
      default:
        console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}.`);
    }
    response.send();
  }
);

app.use(express.json());
```

Answer (score 11):

Referencing the Stripe quickstart server.js code (https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart#provision-access-webhooks), adding the following simple line, placed before `app.use(express.json());` solved the issue for me.

```
app.use('/webhook', express.raw({ type: 'application/json' }));
```

This is telling Express to do something different specifically for the 'webhook' endpoint. And the given 'express.raw...' parameter is what Stripe was already calling as part of their route method for `/webhook`.

*You won't need to rearrange the ordering of your routes/endpoint code or anything.*

Comment: I was struggling with this error for so long, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I was trying to implement the webhook in my react application and I found this solution:

in your server.js file use this code :

```
app.use(
    bodyParser.json({
        verify: function(req, res, buf) {
            req.rawBody = buf;
        }
    })
);
```

and you must use it before the `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

and the in your stripe-file

use this line of code:

```
event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.rawBody, sig, endpointSecret);
```

instead of this line:

```
event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, sig, endpointSecret);
```

Comment: The `rawBody` property in Express was once available, but removed since version 1.5.1. To get the raw request body, you have to put in some middleware before using the bodyParser.

Answer (score 1):

Using `req.rawBody` solved it for me

```
const event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
  req.rawBody,
  sig,
  endpointSecret.value(),
);
```

Comment: That worked for me as well but for some reason the header has 2 values in it. 1 of them is v1 and the other is a t? idk what that means lol

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something in your app is parsing the incoming request to a different format than what the function expects (i.e. JSON). Do you have a middleware or parser configured in your app globally? If so, you'd likely want to disable it Or just add an exception where it doesn't touch the incoming request body that's going to `/webhook` route.

Comment: I have the exact same modules and code like in this example: [https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart#provision-access-webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart#provision-access-webhooks)

Answer (score 0):

In your main file, if you're using express.json. Change it to this and add your webhook endpoint. express.json works same as and is an alternative to bodyparser.

```
app.use(express.json({
verify: (req, res, buf) => {
  if (req.originalUrl.startsWith('/stripe/webhook')) {
    req.rawBody = buf.toString();
  }
},
 }));
```

Then in your webhook function.Change it to this.

```
const signature = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
const rawBody = req.rawBody;

  let event;
  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(rawBody, signature, process.env.WEBHOOKSECRET);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Webhook signature verification failed:', err);
    return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the error you should stringify the payload when calling stripe.webhooks.constructEvent.

example:

```
const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
const body = JSON.stringify(request.body, null, 2);
let event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body, sig, 'your webhook secret');
```

refer to the example provided by stripe
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing

Comment: The error says you need to compare the raw request body. There is no guarantee that the result from using `JSON.stringify()`, will exactly match the original request body sent by Stripe, which is critical when comparing hmac hashes. Do not do this.