# How to use Stripe webhooks in localhost?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm trying to use Stripe webhooks for the first time. Below is the response returned when calling the "/webhook" endpoint

```
{
    "type": "StripeSignatureVerificationError",
    "raw": {
        "message": "No stripe-signature header value was provided."
    },
    "payload": {}
}
```

I've read and followed the steps outlined in the official Stripe documentation, however, it doesn't seem to work properly and I don't get what I'm missing.

```js
// stripe.service.ts

import config from 'config';
import Stripe from 'stripe';

const stripeSecretKey = config.get<string>('stripeSecretKey');

export const stripe = new Stripe(stripeSecretKey, {
  apiVersion: '2023-10-16',
  typescript: true,
});

// webhook.controller.ts 

import config from 'config';

import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

import { stripe } from '@/services/stripe.service';

const stripeWebhookSigningSecret = config.get<string>('stripeWebhookSigningSecret');

export const webhookController = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  const payload = req.body;
  const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'] as string;

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      payload,
      sig,
      stripeWebhookSigningSecret
    );
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send(error);
  }
  console.log(event.type);
  console.log(event.data.object);
  return res.json({ received: true });
};

// routes.ts

  app.post(
'/webhook',
bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/json' }),
webhookController
  );
```

Below is the process I've followed in the CLI

```
- npm run dev
> API is running on http://localhost:3000.

- stripe login

- stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3000/webhook
> Ready! You are using Stripe API Version [2022-11-15]. Your webhook signing secret is whsec_xxx

2023-10-26 23:43:26   --> charge.succeeded [evt_xxx]
2023-10-26 23:43:26  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:3000/webhook [evt_xxx]
2023-10-26 23:43:26   --> payment_intent.succeeded [evt_xxx]
2023-10-26 23:43:26  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:3000/webhook [evt_xxx]
2023-10-26 23:43:26   --> payment_intent.created [evt_xxx]
2023-10-26 23:43:26  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:3000/webhook [evt_xxx]

- stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded
> Setting up fixture for: payment_intent
  Running fixture for: payment_intent
  Trigger succeeded! Check dashboard for event details.
```

I don't receive any data from Stripe webhooks. What am I missing ? Many thanks !

Comment: You don't get nothing, you get a 400 error. What error is that ? If it's a signature verification error, check that you have set the right webhook endpoint secret provided by `stripe listen`, and check this regarding express issues with parsing the signature: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70159949/webhook-signature-verification-failed-with-express-stripe

Comment: Where do you map the `webhookController` function to the `/webhook` URL?  The 400 errors suggest your URL wasn't being found.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've checked and used the correct webhook signing secret starting with "whsec_xxx". I map "webhookController" in the "routes.ts" file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem here: [Stripe - Webhook payload must be provided as a string or a Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76281195/stripe-webhook-payload-must-be-provided-as-a-string-or-a-buffer)

Actually, the middleware `app.use(express.json());` must be placed after the endpoint. Indeed, Express interprets Stripe's signature as an object. I have set a condition in my `createServer.ts`:

```
  // Body parser.
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.path !== '/webhook' ? express.json()(req, res, next) : next();
  });
```

This way, it doesn't apply to `/webhook` endpoint.